# How to cast an array to string after using the jQuery map function?

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization

I am using the [.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function to convert elements to an array, and I'd like to then convert this array into a string:

**javascript:**

```
var selectedElements = $('.data').map(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('selected') ? 'true' : 'false';
});

var A = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday']
A = A + "";

var string = selectedElements  + "";

console.log("\ndebug:");
console.log(selectedElements);
console.log(A);
console.log(string );​
```

**html:**

```
<div class='data'></div>
<div class='data selected'></div>
<div class='data selected'></div>
<div class='data'></div>
<div class='data'></div>
<div class='data'></div>
<div class='data'></div>
```

**Console output:**

```
debug: fiddle.jshell.net:29
["false", "true", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false"]
Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday
[object Object]
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F8ufE/

How do I convert the selectedElements to array ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [`.map()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.

So if you want to get the actual array you can use `get` method, like this:

```
var selectedElements = $('.data').map(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('selected') + "";
}).get();
```

For converting an array to a string you can use `join` method:

```
selectedElements = selectedElements.join()
```

Comment: I've tried join before, but it gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'join'`

Comment: `.get().join()` is ok indeed. I tought you could do only `.join()` without `.get()`.

Comment: @pinouchon Yes, because without using `get` there is no actual array.

Comment: I was confused by the [.map function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) that says `Returns: Array`

Comment: @pinouchon There are 2 map functions, `$.map` utility function and `map` method, you are using this type of map http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 3):

Use the jQuery function [.makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) like so:

```
var selectedElements = $.makeArray($('.data').map(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('selected') ? 'true' : 'false';
}));

var A = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
A = A + "";

var string = selectedElements + "";

console.log("\ndebug:");
console.log(selectedElements);
console.log(A);
console.log(string);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U5LTK/